# XMPP roster getPresence status of a user (java)

Tags: java, android, xmpp, user-presence, rostering

I'm using this code to get the presence status of a user

```
   Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
   Presence userPresence = roster.getPresence(name + "@" + HOST);
```

But `userPresence` always returns `"unavailable"` although the user is online.
So what am I doing wrong, How can I get the presence status of a user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try to get RosterEntries in a Collection using

```
Collection<RosterEntry> collection = roster.getEntries();
```

Then try to traverse each entry and check for presence

```
for (RosterEntry rosterEntry : collection)
  {
    Presence presence = null;
    presence = roster.getPresence(rosterEntry.getUser());

    if(presence.isAvailable())
    {
      //Do Something
    }
    else{
      //Do Something else
    }
  }
```

Comment: but there are too many users, taking all the info and getting the presence status of a person who I want would take much resources, I want to get presence status of a specified user

Comment: @Kar4 then try with your way by just adding this line
Roster.setDefaultSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.accept_all); 
roster.getPresence(name + "@" + HOST+ "/Smack")

tell me if any issues.

Comment: Oh, yes,  it solved the problem, I'm sorry that I forgot to thank you) Thank you very much